# Why do my generated APK showing different results as compared to what it was showing in Android emulator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, android-studio, react-native

I am a newbie when it comes to developing apps.I am working with React Native.I followed the tutorial for '**Android studio and SDK set up**' and set things up properly.

I then created an Android Emulator as Nexus 6. Each time I used to run 'react-native run-android' command I could see the changes accordingly in the emulator.

However my boss asked me to generate an apk file since he wanted to see how things work on his mobile.I followed few tutorials online and managed to generate apk file out of it.

For that I did **Build >> Generate Signed Apk** and so on.
My project is inside C drive. I have made 'MyNewApp' folder and inside that I have my react native folder named 'MyApp'.

Since I had ran

> C:\MyNewApp react-native init MyApp

However the generated apk after installed, it shows nothing but a violet color header with the project parent folder name ('MyNewApp' in this case) in the header and the center of the screen shows 'Hello World' text.

I am actually distraught as things that was working fine on emulator is not working the same after I have generated the apk file.

When I searched for 'Hello world' text globally in the project I found it inside

> C:\MyNewApp\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\activity_main.xml

I am sure I have done something wrong with the process of generating apk and I believe this has got something to do with activity_main.xml.
I just need my generated apk to behave the same way it did in emulator.
Please help as I am stuck badly in this.Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Use command line for building apk. Refer [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#generating-signed-apk)

Comment: If you want to build with Android studio only, checkout [this](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.42/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html#creating-a-release-build-in-android-studio)

Comment: I followed the second solution you gave however I have a doubt with 'Add native code ' section description in that link.Which file should I be adding those native code ?On which file should I create MyReactActivity class

Comment: Thanks a lot Hariks.It worked when I properly followed the first solution. :)